Is there bult-in function in Dialogflow CX to repeat agent's last response in the chatbot?
Is there any system built-in function in DialogFlow cx to Repeat agent's last response. I checked this question but it is for DialogFlow ES.

You can consider transmitting to the same page?

Try $request.last-agent-utterance. It is one of the Built-in parameters (similar to $request.last-user-utterance) but unfortunately not yet documented at https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#request-built-in

Thank you so much for your help. This is extremely helpful. Can you please guide me how to find such functions like  $request.last-agent-utterance myself in the Dialogflow CX if it is not in the documentation.
